# Snap polygons together in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, shapefile

[image]I have two shapefiles representing neighboring counties.  I would like to clean up their common boundary in my ggplot in R.  I know there exists an easy way to do this in ArcGIS, but I'd prefer to stick to using R.  I found the spdep package and tried to use it:

```
ob <- SpatialPolygons(ob@polygons, proj4string=ob@proj4string)

ob2<- SpatialPolygons(ob2@polygons, proj4string=ob2@proj4string)

poly2nb(pl=list(ob,ob2))
```

But this resulted in the following error:

> Error: extends(class(pl), "SpatialPolygons") is not TRUE

Answer (score 1):

We don't have your file but here's something similar:

```
# devtools::install_github("walkerke/tigris")
library(sp)
library(Matrix)
library(spdep)
library(tigris)

me <- counties("maine", detailed=FALSE)
nh <- counties("nh", detailed=FALSE)

neighbors <- poly2nb(as.SpatialPolygons.PolygonsList(c(me@polygons, nh@polygons)))

neighbors
## Neighbour list object:
## Number of regions: 26 
## Number of nonzero links: 114 
## Percentage nonzero weights: 16.86391 
## Average number of links: 4.384615
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help.  Are you able to tell me more about what the various packages do (namely "tigris") and why they are necessary?  Additionally, do you have any advice for going from "neighbors" to plotting the common boundary without artefacts?

Comment: I was just using `tigris` to get county polygons to show how to use that function properly. what _precisely_ are you trying to accomplish? if it's plotting the adjacent counties on a map that won't require that function.

Comment: I have already managed to plot adjacent counties by using the polygons of the individual counties - however the common boundary is not exactly the same for each of the polygons and this results in artifacts and the plot looking scraggy.